# Where does 3-D become 2-D?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I have been taught that there is a clear distinction between the arithmetic involving objects in 2-D and objects in 3-D. As time went by I became better at solving 3-D geometry problems. For example, let us take a problem:

> The image of a point A(2,3) on a line L: 3x + 4y = 12 is?

This would involve taking a point (a,b) which is the point of the image, and since the image and the object are equidistant from the line, we substitute (a+2/2, b+3/2) to the equation of line L. Now we go through a computation of finding the two slopes and making sure they are 90 degrees.

However after learning 3-D geometry, I could call the line:

$$\frac{3x-12}{4} = \frac{-y}{1}$$

and hence my line can be parameterized as
$$L1 = \{\frac{4t+12}{3}, -t\}$$

Now I can use dot products and go ahead and solve how I would if it was a 3-D problem.

Now my question is, how and when can I change my 2-D problems to a 3-D geometry or even a vector problem (I have also been taught about the interconversion of 3-D cartesian equations to vector equations)?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about 2-D and 3-D: What you call 3-D still seems to involve only 2 dimensions. Eg. your parametrization is presumably a vector of 2 elements? In 2D, you generally work with vectors of the form $[x, y]$, and in 3D, you have 3 coordinates $[x,y,z]$. Generally, working in $n$ dimensions involves $n$ coordinates and/or vectors with $n$ components.

Comment: In your post, you seem to distinguish between vector calculus (what you call "3D"), and formulating the problem in terms of defining equations. Neither approach is limited to a particular dimension.

Comment: For example, in $n$ dimensions, you could describe a line either way: (1) By a starting point, plus a parameter $t$ times a vector of the direction, or (2) $n-1$ intersecting planes, each one given by a scalar equation.

Comment: I was taught that a line in 3D can never be expressed as some linear combination of x, y and z. However, it can be expressed as the intersection of two planes, which makes the equation of line as x/l = y/m = z/n . For me doing arithemetic on line of this format is easier. So can I always turn 2D lines(Ax+By+C = 0), as a set of equation, and solve from there. And I also wanted to know is there any interesting properties I can take advantage of when I write it in a set of equation.

Comment: What you wrote is quite sloppy, it seems that you were poorly taught. Consider reading a textbook, not just your class notes.